# I'm using mongoose and would like to go all members and use the results of each research individually

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm using mongoose and would like to go all members and use the results of each research individually:

1. Everytime I use **`Model.find()`**, I get null.
2. I have no idea how to search all elements individually.

The following code contains what I've done

```
async.waterfall([
  function (done) {
    user.find({}).exec(function (err, user) {
      done(err, user);
    });
  },
  function (user, done) {
      console.log(user.firstName);
  }
], function (err) {
  console.log(err);
});
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result which you get from the `User.find()` is an array of user objects. Therefore `Array.firstname` will be `null`.

```
async.waterfall([
  function (done) {
    user.find({}).exec(function (err, user) {
      done(err, user);
    });
  },
  function (users, done) {
      users.forEach(function(user) {
          console.log(user.firstName);
      });
      done(null, users);
  }
], function (err) {
  console.log(err);
});
```